# Automapper UseDestinationValue() or Ignore() both setting integer destination value to 0

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

First of all there are several similar questions and I have tried looking at them every where but none of them worked .

I have this mapping code

```
var updateEntities = await _dbContext.AnswerAnchors.Where(x => x.SurveyResultId == surveyResultId).ToListAsync();
updateEntities = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AnswerAnchorsDomainModel>, List<AnswerAnchors>>(anchors, updateEntities);
_dbContext.UpdateRange(updateEntities);
```

And here is my destination Object structure .

```
public class AnswerAnchors : BaseEntity<long>
    {
        public long SurveyResultId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset AnchorDate { get; set; }
        public string AnchorDescription { get; set; }
    }


public class BaseEntity<T> : IBaseEntity
        where T : struct
    {
        [Key]
        public T Id { get; set; }
    }
```

What is happening is the existing `Id` needs to be mapped and not overwritten by the destination under any circumstances because entity framework needs to update the entity. However whenever the mapping happens the `Id` property gets overwritten to zero(0). I tried using `opt.Ignore()` and `opt.UseDestinationValue()` but none of them retains the destination `Id` value.

Here is the profile -

```
CreateMap<AnswerAnchorsDomainModel, AnswerAnchors>()
                .ForMember(anchor => anchor.Id, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
                .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
           {
               dest.CreatedBy = "";
               dest.LastUpdateBy = "";
               dest.CreateOn = DateTimeOffset.Now;
               dest.UpdateOn = DateTimeOffset.Now;
           });
```

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

My work around to this, fetching all data from repo, do a deep clone, then `_context.Entry(entity here).State = EntityState.Detached;` mapping all retaliated `object _mapper.Map(source, destination)` assigning the id's back using the clone object .... witch change the state back to modified, then await `_repo.SaveAllAsync()` ....I do this for each related object. Not the best of ways, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround and better way is the get updateEntities from repo witch contains the id properties in detached state  ...

then foreach loop the AnswerAnchorsDomainModel assighn the id's with query in updateEntities to AnswerAnchorsDomainModel

_mapper.Map, List>(anchors, 
updateEntities);

Change the updateEntities state back to modified.

Save Changes...

Done..

This way you map the correct id's to the update enity's ...

now EF and in my case EFcore, know's what to update and what to add.